# Marionette: How to prepend a LayoutView as a row into a CompositView table?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, view, marionette, composite

I'm building a table with Backbone.js and Marionette.js.  My collection of models creates the rows in the table, that get inserted into the `<tbody>`.

I want to attach 1 single row at the top of the table which is not part of my collection.  It's a previously defined `LayoutView`.

Usually I would just add another region, but because I'm working with a table, I cannot add extra `div`'s to the `tbody` as the table will spit it out of the table as its not a `<tr>` within a `<tbody>`.

Below is my attempt at building this in my `onShow` function of the CompositView:

```
var SetAllTargets = Backbone.Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
    template: JST["common/cubes/table/set-all-rows"],
    tagName: "tr",
    className: "set-all-targets"
});


App.Table = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({

    template: JST["common/targets/layout"],
    className: "targets",
    childView: RowTarget,
    childViewContainer: "tbody",

    regions: {
        targetsRegion: ".targets-region"
    },

    onShow: function() {
        var setAllTargetsRow = new SetAllTargets();
        var setAllTargetsRegion = "<tr class='target set-all-targets'></tr>";
        this.$el.find("tbody").prepend(setAllTargetsRegion);
        this.$el.find(".set-all-targets").show(setAllTargetsRow);
    }
)};
```

Another attempt was to put the

```
<tr class='target set-all-targets'> ...child elements here </tr>
```

into the template and attach the `view.el` in my `onShow` function like this:

```
    onShow: function() {    
        var setAllTargetsRow = new SetAllTargets();
        this.$el.find("tbody").prepend(setAllTargetsRow.el);
    }
```

But that results in just the html `<tr class='target set-all-targets'></tr>` being placed into the top of the table, but none of the child elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`CollectionView.addChild`](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.2/marionette.collectionview.html#collectionviews-addchild) method on your composite to insert something before your collection is rendered:

```
onBeforeRenderCollection: function() {
    this.addChild(null, <View>, 0);
}
```

[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7919kLrk/) for an example of it in action.

Comment: I ended up inserting an extra row into my header - but this is way cleaner.  I'll update my project with this as soon as I can.  Thanks!